How to substitute a Blank value with the number '0' in a DAX Measure in Power BI?
How do I fill in the blanks in a table with the number '0'in a measure?
Measure:
ResolvedMeasure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet1'[Number]), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],Sheet1[Resolved]))

*What needs to be done so that the blank spaces in the 'resolved column' change to Zero?
*I've attempted to add '+0' at the end of the measure; however doing so pulled in the data that was not associated with the filtered month and year of July,2024.
Measure with plus 0:
ResolvedMeasure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet1'[Number]), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],Sheet1[Resolved]))+0

*What needs to be done so that the blank spaces in the 'resolved column' change to Zero, without the measure pulling in additional data not associated with the month and year the page is filtered on?

Can you please provide some mock data so I can replicate this issue?

maybe you can try this
Measure = if(not(ISBLANK([open]))&&ISBLANK([resolve]),0,[resolve])

